# If Statement Failing when Statement Becomes False

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, runtime-error

Evening I have created a Sub Function. Which in its first instance works, however, if after it has run the If and I remove a value and make the If Statement False. It arrives with the Debug Dialogue Runtime Error '13' (Type Mismatch).

I have ran through this many times, it is similar to other If Statements within the VBA Code, but this is the only one that fails. I only have limited knowledge of VBA Programming, so any assistance on this matter would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub BenifitCheck()

If Not IsEmpty(TB_HoursSaved.Value) And Not IsEmpty(TB_TimeAllocation.Value) And Not 
  TB_HoursSaved.Value = "" And Not TB_TimeAllocation.Value = "" And TB_HoursSaved.Value / 
  TB_TimeAllocation.Value > 10 Then
  Let TB_Result = "PASSED"
  TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(84, 130, 53)
  TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(146, 208, 80)
  TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  ElseIf Not IsEmpty(TB_HoursSaved.Value) And Not IsEmpty(TB_TimeAllocation.Value) And Not 
  TB_HoursSaved.Value = "" And Not TB_TimeAllocation.Value = "" And TB_HoursSaved.Value / 
  TB_TimeAllocation.Value >= 5 And TB_HoursSaved.Value / TB_TimeAllocation.Value < 10 Then
  Let TB_Result = "REVIEW"
  TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
  TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
  TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  ElseIf Not IsEmpty(TB_HoursSaved.Value) And Not IsEmpty(TB_TimeAllocation.Value) And Not 
  TB_HoursSaved.Value = "" And Not TB_TimeAllocation.Value = "" And TB_HoursSaved.Value / 
  TB_TimeAllocation.Value < 5 Then
  Let TB_Result = "FAIL"
  TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  Else
  TB_Result = ""
  TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

On Error Resume Next
Call Error

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: It highlights the First Line. When I try and step through it stays on this line, but the statement works initially. Then when it becomes false it fails.

Comment: I’ve tried that, but it still failed after initially functioning. One thing I haven’t tried is If IsEmpty(TB....Value), and nest it in the Else function.

Comment: try adding parens around the division ... `... And (TB_HoursSaved.Value / 
  TB_TimeAllocation.Value > 10)`. If that does not work, then isolate which exact statement on the first line is failing. Try them 1 by 1 in the debug window. You will most likely catch the issue that way.

Comment: I've amended the code to a nested if, still works until I make the statement false.

This is the line which I believe is failing - If (TB_HoursSaved.Value / TB_TimeAllocation.Value) > 10 Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be greatly simplified by thinking a little more carefully about what you want to achieve with your sub.  i.e. you are doing a check and want to raise an error if the check fails.

Such an action is quite common and is often best achieved by encapsulating the check in it own function so you can write code like 'if Not Check Passes then do error condition'

So I'd rewrite you sub in the following way

```
Sub Test()

    If Not BenefitCheckPasses Then Err.raise 17

    ' Code for successful benefit check
End Sub

Private Function BenefitCheckPasses() As Boolean

    BenefitCheckPasses = False

    If IsEmpty(TB_HoursSaved.Value) Then Exit Function
    If IsEmpty(TB_TimeAllocation.Value) Then Exit Function
    If TB_HoursSaved.Value = "" Then Exit Function
    If TB_TimeAllocation.Value = "" Then Exit Function

    BenefitCheckPasses = True

    Dim Ratio As Double
    Ratio = TB_HoursSaved.Value / TB_TimeAllocation.Value

    Select Case Ratio

        Case Is > 10

            TB_Result = "PASSED"
            TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(84, 130, 53)
            TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(146, 208, 80)
            TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

        Case Is > 5

            TB_Result = "REVIEW"
            TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
            TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
            TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

        Case Else

            Let TB_Result = "FAIL"
            TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    End Select

End Function
```

As you can see, you had an else clause that was entirely irrelevant, and also unexecutable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance, with your advice I have got the code to do as it should:

```
Private Sub BenifitCheck()

If Not IsEmpty(TB_HoursSaved.Value) And Not IsEmpty(TB_TimeAllocation.Value) And Not 
TB_HoursSaved.Value = "" And Not TB_TimeAllocation.Value = "" Then

    If (TB_HoursSaved.Value / TB_TimeAllocation.Value) > 10 Then
    Let TB_Result = "PASSED"
    TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(84, 130, 53)
    TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    ElseIf (TB_HoursSaved.Value / TB_TimeAllocation.Value) >= 5 And (TB_HoursSaved.Value / TB_TimeAllocation.Value) < 10 Then
    Let TB_Result = "REVIEW"
    TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    ElseIf (TB_HoursSaved.Value / TB_TimeAllocation.Value) < 5 Then
    Let TB_Result = "FAIL"
    TB_Result.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    ElseIf TB_BenifitRatio.Value = "" Then
    TB_Result = ""
    TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    End If

Else: Let TB_Result = ""
TB_BenifitRatio.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
TB_BenifitRatio.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Let` is no longer needed: